# Monitoring Linux Servers behind squid proxy via Nagioscore

Tags: nagios

This is my first post here, please help me.

I want to monitor a few redhat servers which are behind a squid proxy server. I have done the below configuration:

RedHat Node behind proxy server configuration:-
I have installed nrpe and also copied check_disk, check_cpu and check_mem plugins under /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins.

I also added the below lines in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg file.

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,Squid_Proxy_server_IP
command[check_disk]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$
command[check_cpu]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_cpu -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
command[check_mem]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mem -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -W $ARG3$ -C $ARG4$
```

Squid Proxy Server Configuration:-
I have also installed nrpe in squid proxy server and copied check_disk, check_cpu, check_mem, check_nrpe and check_ping plugins under /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins. I also added the below lines in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg file.

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,Nagios_server_IP
command[check_disk]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$
command[check_cpu]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_cpu -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
command[check_mem]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mem -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -W $ARG3$ -C $ARG4$
command[check_proxy]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -t 60 -H $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -a $ARG3$ $ARG4$
command[check_ping]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H $ARG1$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
```

If I run the below command from squid proxy server to RedHat server, I can get a correct output.

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H RedHat_IP -c check_disk -a 20% 10% /app
```

Also If I run the below command from nagios server to squid proxy server, I can get a correct output.

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H Proxy_server_IP -c check_disk -a 20% 10% /app
```

But if I run the below command to check the RedHat server status directly from nagios server via Proxy server I get "Error: Unable to read the output".

```
./check_nrpe -H Proxy_node_IP -c check_proxy -a RedHat_IP_behind_Proxy check_disk "20% 10% /app"
```

Please help me as it has become quite critical for our environment.

Comment: I don't know details of Nagios, but I doubt that it uses HTTP(S) compatible protocol with its remote communication. Squid is an HTTP(S) proxy, which uses HTTP(S). You should look into SSH tunneling for this use case.

Comment: You should try running `check_nrpe -H Proxy_node_IP (localhost) -c check_proxy -a RedHat_IP_behind_Proxy check_disk "20% 10% /app"` from the *squid* server, and not the nagios server. Hopefully you'll get some more useful feedback on what's failing instead of the generic "unable to read output".

Comment: NRPE uses TCP port 5666. I doubt you will not be able proxy NRPE through Squid. Is allowing port 5666 through your firewall out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

do you have issue if check_by_ssh from Nagios?

Squid should be prepared:

acl localnet src X.X.X.X/X

Next, add the SSH port as a safe port by adding the following line:

acl Safe_ports port 22

Comment: Thanks for the reply...
I am using nrpe because SSH is not allowed in our environment. i am also not the owner of squid proxy server. I will discuss your suggested approach with my teamate.
Should I add port 5666 as a safe port in squid proxy configuration?.

Comment: Adding 5666 as a safe port would definitly be worth a try.